# How should I filter data in Strapi by $and operator

Tags: next.js, strapi

I want to filter my table data by `createdAt`,`status_invitor` and `status_invited`. I write query Like this

```js
const query = qs.stringify({
  filters: {
    $and: {
      createdAt: { $gte: firstDayOfTheMonth },
      createdAt: { $lt: lastDayOfTheMonth },
    },
    $and: {
      status_invitor: statusFilter
    },
    status_invited: statusFilter,
  },
});
```

but is not working correctly

Comment: Do you need the `$and` entries? Is it not `$and` by default when you add multiple filters? Also what is `statusFilter`?

Comment: statusFilter is value for status_invitro and status_invited

Answer (score 0):

The filters are combined by default so unless I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, you don't need to use the `$and` operator.

```js
const query = qs.stringify({
  filters: {
    createdAt: { $gte: firstDayOfTheMonth },
    createdAt: { $lt: lastDayOfTheMonth },
    status_invitor: statusFilter,
    status_invited: statusFilter,
  },
});
```

If you do want to mix `AND` and `OR` filters then you need to specify an array. You can see examples of that here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#complex-filtering

Comment: I try your code but is not working correctly.

Comment: @SayedHassanHussaini Can you explain further what you are trying to achieve? Are they all `and` conditions or is there a mix of `and` and `or`? Like `((a or b) and c)`? When you say it's not working are you not getting any results or are you not getting the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project where I wanted to query more than one field with a search term. This is the code I used to get it working. I think all you need to do is change the $or for the $and and it should work.

```
    const query = qs.stringify( {
    filters: {
        $or: [
            { name: { $contains: term }},
            { venue: { $contains: term } },
            { performers: { $contains: term } },
            { description: { $contains: term } },
        ],
    },
},
)
```